# Logic app can't authenticate with SharePoint. Where to do I find Client ID/Secret?

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication, azure, logic-app

I have a logic application in Microsoft Azure that connects to a SharePoint Online list and retrieves items  to move to blob storage. This worked until recently where the execution for the syncing event broke down.

The settings for the application look like the following:
[image]

My thinking is that the client id/secret may no longer be current and need to be regenerated, however I'm unsure where these settings are found? Where can I find them so I can check that they are correct?